# Union and Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have two queries that I'm combining with a UNION operation:

```
DECLARE @BeginningOfYear AS date

SET @BeginningOfYear = smalldatetimefromparts(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1, 0, 0)

SELECT

  groupname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
  CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

FROM zendeskticketexport

WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

GROUP BY groupname

UNION

SELECT

  groupname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
  CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

FROM zendeskunclosedticketexport

WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

GROUP BY groupname
```

The result of this query:

```
groupname       LW      YTD     Average Per Week
DC Maintenance  179     1831    184
DC QC1          85      647     64
DC Web Ops      69      400     40
DC Maintenance  68      86      8
DC QC1          18      20      2
DC Web Ops      53      80      8
```

I would like to sum up the numbers for each of the groups in the resulting queries, but I don't know how to do this without creating a temporary table...I would like to avoid doing so because I feel it would be an unnecessary complication to the query. I'm thinking on doing on rather doing a full join...would that be more appropriate or is a temp table the way to go on this one?

EDIT: I should mention there's a unique identifier on both of the tables - let's call it ID - but if one ID exists on a table, it doesn't exist on the other - this is the reason why I'm thinking a FULL join might be appropriate.

Comment: Can you please show expected output

Comment: Do the `UNION [ALL]` part in a derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do with derived table like this

```
select p.groupname,sum(p.LW) as LW,sum(p.YTD) as YTD,sum(p.[Average Per Week]) as Average Per Week from
  (SELECT

  groupname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
  CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

FROM zendeskticketexport

WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

GROUP BY groupname

UNION

SELECT

  groupname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
  CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

FROM zendeskunclosedticketexport

WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

GROUP BY groupname) as p
group by p.groupname
```

or you can do with **CTE**

```
;with cte
(SELECT

      groupname,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
      SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
      CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

    FROM zendeskticketexport

    WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

    GROUP BY groupname

    UNION

    SELECT

      groupname,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
      SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
      CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'

    FROM zendeskunclosedticketexport

    WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')

    GROUP BY groupname) 
select p.groupname,sum(p.LW) as LW,sum(p.YTD) as YTD,sum(p.[Average Per Week]) as Average Per Week 
from from cte GROUP BY groupname
```

Comment: Sweet! The derived table example is really straight forward. Thank you.

Comment: No need to do `UNION ALL`?

Comment: No, I don't believe a union all would work because the I'm trying to sum up the distinct values...I believe for a union all to remove duplicate rows the rows would need to be exactly the same. I could be misunderstanding the point you're trying to make though.

Answer (score 0):

Did I get you right here, you want the total sums and counts - for both tables?

```
SELECT
  groupname,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LW',
  SUM(CASE WHEN ticketcreateddate > @BeginningOfYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD',
  CAST(COUNT(*) / DATEDIFF(WEEK, @BeginningOfYear, GETDATE()) AS float) AS 'Average Per Week'
(
  SELECT groupname, ticketcreateddate
  FROM zendeskunclosedticketexport
  WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT groupname, ticketcreateddate
  FROM zendeskunclosedticketexport
  WHERE groupname IN ('DC Web Ops', 'DC Maintenance', 'DC QC1')
)
GROUP BY groupname
```